# Jekyll: Specify whether a plugin is active in the development environment

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

In my Jekyll site, I'm using the [`minify-html`](https://github.com/octopress/minify-html) plugin. However, it causes the site build time to increase from 2-20 seconds to nearly 5 minutes, which is unacceptable during development. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/octopress/minify-html/blob/master/README.md):

> After installing, Jekyll's HTML output will be minified by default. If you configure `env` in your Jekyll configuration, HTML will be minified only when
>   `env` is set to production.
>
> ```
> env: production
> ```

This documentation is useless as it doesn't explain *how* to configure `env`. As can be expected, setting `env: production` in `_config.yml` has no effect, as it doesn't specify *what* should vary based on environment. I've spent quite a lot of time searching the internet for how to make this work, but I've turned up nothing. As far as I can tell, `env`, along with any other method to vary by environment, is totally undocumented in Jekyll.

**How can I set `minify-html` to only run when I call `JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build`?**

PS: In case it's relevant, I installed `minify-html` by adding it to my Gemfile and running `bundle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no `env` variable set in `_config.yml``=> minification

`env: production` => minification

`env: yolo or whatever or dev` => no minification

You can have a development command, using a development config file that will override the default `_config.yml`. [See command options](http://Specify%20config%20files%20instead%20of%20using%20_config.yml%20automatically.%20Settings%20in%20later%20files%20override%20settings%20in%20earlier%20files.)

In a new **_config_dev.yml**, set :

```
env: dev
```

To serve minified : `jekyll serve`.

To serve unminified : `jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml`

Comment: The joys of undocumented features! According to `jekyll --help`, there's no way to specify a config file from the command line. Yet the command you gave works.

Comment: @ScottSeverance: It's documented on the website: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#build-command-options

Comment: it's way down on the page under configurations https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#build-command-options